# Call Dart method from JS in Flutter Web

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web

For a Webview relate feature I had used Method channels to open Webview through Native Android & iOS code and I am opening a website in it, I was getting callback from JS to native code in mobile platforms.
For Android I was providing a class whose method is getting called from JS,
It looks something like this:

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "nativeCommunicator")

webView.loadUrl("SOME_URL")

…

class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Activity) {
  @JavascriptInterface
  fun postMessage(text: String) {
    println("WebAppInterface.message($text)")
    //send back to flutter
  }
}
```

Which seems quite straightforward way to get callback from js to my code.

Now I am trying to do this in Flutter Web
I opened the website by calling

```
import 'package:js/js.dart';
...
js.context.callMethod('open', 'SOME_URL', '_self');
```

Which works fine, Now I am trying to get callback by creating this class

```
@JS()
library native_communicator;

import 'package:js/js.dart';
@JS('nativeCommunicator')
class NativeCommunicator{

 @JS('postMessage')
 external static set _postMessage(void Function(String text) f);


 @JS()
 external static void postMessage();

}

void setJSCallbackFunction(void Function(String text) postMessageFunction) {
 NativeCommunicator._postMessage = allowInterop(postMessageFunction);
}
```

I am calling setJSCallbackFunction and passing my function as param, but it keeps giving me runtime error that
It can not find ‘postMessage’, I tried some other way which leads to can not find ‘nativeCommunicator’ error,
Can anyone point out how to do this right?
I need to call a dart method from js.

Answer (score 9):

#### Making a Dart function callable from JavaScript

If you pass a Dart function to a JavaScript API as an argument, wrap the Dart function using `allowInterop()` or `allowInteropCaptureThis()`.

To make a Dart function callable from JavaScript by name, use a setter annotated with `@JS()`.

Sample:

```dart
@JS()
library callable_function;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

/// Allows assigning a function to be callable from `window.functionName()`
@JS('functionName')
external set _functionName(void Function() f);

void _someDartFunction() {
  print('Hello from Dart!');
}

void main() {
  _functionName = allowInterop(_someDartFunction);
  // JavaScript code may now call `functionName()` or `window.functionName()`.
}
```

*From [`package:js` docs](https://pub.dev/packages/js#making-a-dart-function-callable-from-javascript)*

### Changes -

```dart
@JS()
library native_communicator;

import 'package:js/js.dart';
@JS('nativeCommunicator')
class NativeCommunicator{

 @JS('postMessage')
 external static set _postMessage(void Function(String text) f);

// No need to do this as 'allowInterop()' will do the necessary.
//
// @JS()
// external static void postMessage();
//
// }

void setJSCallbackFunction(void Function(String text) postMessageFunction) {
 NativeCommunicator._postMessage = allowInterop(postMessageFunction);
}
```

```dart
import 'path/to/setJSCallbackFunction-file';

void main() {
    setJSCallbackFunction(param);
}
```

#### Steps to debug

1. Look for generated js file - `build/web/main.dart.js`
2. Try using search to locate the function. (Here, `postMessage`)
3. If you can't find it, then you might have missed some annotations or might not have called `allowInterop()` in `main()`
4. If you are able to find it but it isn't working, check your dart function and make sure you are passing the right parameters. Also, make sure that `dart.main.js` is in scope.

```html
<script src"path/to/dart.main.js">
window.functionName(); // or functionName()
</script>
```

> Prefer to define the js function as a top-level function which can be called with `window.functionName()` or `functionName()`

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for `allowInterop` function from `dart:js` library: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-js/dart-js-library.html

Sample code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:js/js_util.dart';

String dartFunc(String str) {
  return 'Inside dartFunc: ' + str;
}

void main() {
  setProperty(window, 'dartFunc', allowInterop(dartFunc));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: It's right there in my code. please check, 
Did you try it and had working sample?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it. I've updated the answer with some sample code.

Comment: How do you call it from js?

Comment: It's defined on the global `window` object, so you can reference it by `dartFunc` or `window.dartFunc`

Comment: Are there any security implications to consider when using this solution? Is it safe as long as I give precise control to a specific method?