# How to call a Dart async function from JavaScript

Tags: flutter, function, dart

I try to return data from a dart async function from javascript

and i have this `js._DartObject.new {Symbol(_dartObj): _…e.new}` as result

I want to know how to call a dart async function in javascript that return a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Dart method from JS in Flutter Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423861/call-dart-method-from-js-in-flutter-web)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.