# How to convert a Dart Future to a Javascript Promise for flutter webview

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, dart2js

I have used webview_flutter to load my site url, and used a JavaScriptChannel for two way communication between javascript and dart, as i want some native result from Android/IOS platform to javascript.

In Flutter

```
controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..addJavaScriptChannel('FlutterChannel',
      onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) async {
    
        //Here i am doing some operation and returning a result as
        controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult('window.function($result)');
    
  })
  ..loadRequest(
    Uri.parse(
        'https://demo.com/')
  );
```

In JavaScript to interact with flutter channel-

```
var params = {'key':'alternate_preference','value': ''}; 
var data = { plugin: 'SharedPref', method: 'fetch', params: [params] };
FlutterChannel.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data))
```

To capture result in javascript-

```
function flutterResponseFunc(flutterResult) {
   console.log(flutterResult);
}
window.function= flutterResponseFunc;
```

How can i capture the result in callback of FlutterChannel.postMessage itself instead of creating a different function for result in js. Like Promise.then function in javascript.

[image]

I have gone through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76871848)

But it seems like a platform specific(i.e. for web platform only), as i can not use dart:js_interop & dart:html libs for Android/IOS platform. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: _Author of the other answer here_ If I understand you correctly, why don't you use the code for my other answer?
because it's not supported on mobile/ios? you can use a conditional import to only import the package if youre on Chrome. Unless (which I think) I haven't understood your question.

Comment: @MedelG  dart:html, dart:js and dart:js_util these libs are not supported outside the web context. Functionality that depends on them will fail at runtime in Flutter mobile

Comment: But you can conditionally import them, check if your running on web or not and import based on that

Comment: I am not running this from web. I am just loading url in webview for flutter mobile and added communication from Flutter to JS and vice versa using JavaScript Channel in Flutter

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [signature of the `addJavaScriptChannel` function](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController/addJavaScriptChannel.html) it's not possible to provide a result to `postMessage()`.

```dart
Future<void> addJavaScriptChannel(
    String name,
    {required void onMessageReceived(
        JavaScriptMessage
    )}
)
```

The `onMessageReceived` doesn't return any value after invocation and `JavaScriptMessage` doesn't provide a callback to invoke with data.

So any aproach you could take would require you to build a custom solution with non-enforcable contracts within JS. As this is complex and error prone, it might be easier to just handle the result as you're doing already.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to translate the function between languages. You can run simple codes through flutter. I left an example from my own use for easier understanding.

```
..addJavaScriptChannel(
    'consolePrint',
    onMessageReceived: (value) {
      final fileName = DateTime.now().toString().replaceAll(':', '-');
      final Map linkList = jsonDecode(value.message.toString());

      int totalCalculate(Map returnValue) {
        if (returnValue.containsValue(null)) {
          returnValue.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
          return returnValue.length;
        }
        return returnValue.length;
      }

      ProgressBar.total = 0;
      ProgressBar.progressValue.value = 0;
      ProgressBar.total = totalCalculate(linkList);
      linkList.forEach((key, value) {
        if (value != null) {
          downloadJpg(
              index: int.parse(key),
              url: value,
              fileNmae: fileName,
              total: linkList.length);
        }
      });
    },
  );
```

Run and create a function from flutter. Then return the result to a channel.
consolePrint is the name of my channel here

```
void getLinkMap(WebViewController controller) async {
  try {
    await controller.runJavaScript('''
                  function getImages() {
                    var json = {};
                    var liList = document.querySelectorAll("body > div.main-content > div.ng-scope > div.content > div:nth-child(3) > div.modal-content.mega-image > section > ul > li")
                    liList.forEach(function list(value, index) {
                      var img = value.querySelector('img');
                      var hdImage = img.getAttribute("hd-image");
                      json[index] = hdImage;
                    });
                    consolePrint.postMessage(JSON.stringify(json));
                  };
                  window.onload = getImages();
              ''');
  } catch (e) {
    log('error code: $e',
        time: DateTime.now(), name: 'func:getLinkMap');
  }
}
```

Comment: @FurrkanBora This is just a one way communication i.e. JS->Flutter. How you are achieving 2 way communication and perform some action on basis of result returned from flutter to JS.

Comment: I cannot explain more than that. It is normal to get stuck sometimes. Take a good nap and look at it again. I cannot provide free code refactoring. If it is important, send me 30 bucs and I will refactor that part of your code. 
If you want to do it on your own, this explanation is all you need to do it.
else I prefer cryptocurrencies.

its flutter -> js -> flutter btw

Comment: Thanks brother. You are on a wrong platform. No one will pay you here.