# How can I convert various Dart data types to JavaScript for use in a browser?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, type-conversion

I'm working on a Dart web project and frequently need to interoperate with JavaScript. I'm familiar with the [`dart:js`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.0/dart-js/dart-js-library.html) library, but I'm struggling to convert various Dart data types to their JavaScript counterparts.

For instance, I attempted converting a Dart `List` to a JavaScript array:

```dart
List<String> fruits = ['apple', 'banana'];
js.context['myJsArray'] = fruits;  // Is this the right approach?
```

I'm unsure if this is the correct way. Similarly, I'm puzzled about handling other types like primitives, `maps`, custom objects, etc.

**How can I effectively convert and expose these Dart data types to JavaScript using [`dart:js`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.0/dart-js/dart-js-library.html)?**

My end goal is that I can call them in the browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Setup

Import the necessary import:

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
```

### 1. Primitives

Dart primitives are *automatically* converted to their JavaScript counterparts when passed through `dart:js`.

The `js.context` allows you to access the global JavaScript context, making Dart variables and functions available to JavaScript.

```dart
void convertPrimitives() {
  int myInt = 123;
  double myDouble = 123.456;
  String myString = "Hello from Dart!";
  bool myBool = true;

  js.context['myJsInt'] = myInt;
  js.context['myJsDouble'] = myDouble;
  js.context['myJsString'] = myString;
  js.context['myJsBool'] = myBool;
}
```

### 2. Special values

```dart
void convertSpecialValues() {
  js.context['myJsNull'] = null;
}
```

### 3. Lists

```dart
void convertList() {
  List<String> myList = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"];
  js.context['myJsArray'] = js.JsArray.from(myList);
}
```

### 4. Maps and Objects

Using [`JsObject.jsify`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.7/dart-js/JsObject/JsObject.jsify.html)

```dart
void convertMap() {
  Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
    'name': 'John',
    'age': 25
  };
  js.context['myJsObject'] = js.JsObject.jsify(myMap);
}
```

### 5. Functions

```dart
void convertFunction() {
  js.context['myJsFunction'] = (String msg) {
    print("Message from JS: $msg");
  };
}
```

### 6. Custom Dart Objects

You can use `JsObject.jsify()`

```dart
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'age': age
    };
  }
}

void convertCustomObject() {
  Person john = Person("John", 25);
  js.context['myJsPerson'] = js.JsObject.jsify(john.toJson());
}
```

### 7. `Future` to `Promise`

```dart
oid convertFutureToPromise() {
  js.context['fetchGreetingAsPromise'] =
      js.JsFunction.withThis((_this, resolve, reject) {
    fetchGreeting().then((result) {
      resolve.apply([result]);
    }).catchError((error) {
      reject.apply([error.toString()]);
    });
  });
}

Future<String> fetchGreeting() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return "Hello from Dart!";
}
```

**On the Javascript side:**

```dart
const promise = new Promise(window.fetchGreetingAsPromise);
promise.then(result => {
  console.log(result);  // Should print: "Hello from Dart!" after 2 seconds
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

### Browser Console

Once the page is loaded, open the browser's console and manually access the converted Dart variables and functions. Here are some commands you can run:

- Accessing converted variables:

```js
console.log(window.myJsInt);          // Should print: 123
console.log(window.myJsString);       // Should print: "Hello from Dart!"
console.log(window.myJsArray[1]);     // Should print: "banana"
console.log(window.myJsObject.name);  // Should print: "John"
```

- Calling the exposed Dart function:

```js
window.myJsFunction("Hi there, Dart!"); //  "Hi there, Dart!"
```

- Calling the promise

```js
const promise = new Promise(window.fetchGreetingAsPromise);
promise.then(result => {
  console.log(result);  // Should print: "Hello from Dart!" after 2 seconds
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

[image: Browser console]

### Complete code

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

void main() {
  convertPrimitives();
  convertSpecialValues();
  convertList();
  convertMap();
  convertFunction();
  convertCustomObject();
  convertFutureToPromise();
}

void convertPrimitives() {
  int myInt = 123;
  double myDouble = 123.456;
  String myString = "Hello from Dart!";
  bool myBool = true;

  js.context['myJsInt'] = myInt;
  js.context['myJsDouble'] = myDouble;
  js.context['myJsString'] = myString;
  js.context['myJsBool'] = myBool;
}

void convertSpecialValues() {
  js.context['myJsNull'] = null;
}

void convertList() {
  List<String> myList = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"];
  js.context['myJsArray'] = js.JsArray.from(myList);
}

void convertMap() {
  Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {'name': 'John', 'age': 25};
  js.context['myJsObject'] = js.JsObject.jsify(myMap);
}

void convertFunction() {
  js.context['myJsFunction'] = (String msg) {
    print("Message from JS: $msg");
  };
}

class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {'name': name, 'age': age};
  }
}

void convertCustomObject() {
  Person john = Person("John", 25);
  js.context['myJsPerson'] = js.JsObject.jsify(john.toJson());
}

void convertFutureToPromise() {
  js.context['fetchGreetingAsPromise'] =
      js.JsFunction.withThis((_this, resolve, reject) {
    fetchGreeting().then((result) {
      resolve.apply([result]);
    }).catchError((error) {
      reject.apply([error.toString()]);
    });
  });
}

Future<String> fetchGreeting() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return "Hello from Dart!";
}
```

#### See also

- [Call Dart method from JS in Flutter Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423861/call-dart-method-from-js-in-flutter-web)
- [The `dart:js` documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/master/pkg/js)